# Is there any way to add to the .replace function in python?

Tags: python

Im a beginner to python and I am wondering whether I can add a "+1" to my s.replace function

```
def growth(word, letter):
  result = ""
  for x in range(len(word)):
    for j in range(x + 1):
      result = word.replace(letter,letter + "*")
  return result

print(growth('hello', 'l'))
```

that is my code above and when I do run this code I get the value of `hel*l*o`
I am expecting this answer but I want to find a way to double it every time the letter "l" or whatever is set shows up.

Thank you

Comment: Unclear. What do you want to achieve here? Do you want to double all occurances of the given letter? Why the double loop?

Comment: In each iteration of the loop, you overwrite `result`with the same replacement. Instead, you might mean to initialize `result` as `word` and then do `result = result.replace(...)`, or maybe (more likely) the loop is just not needed at all.

Comment: @tobias_k I don't think a loop is even needed here at all.  EDIT: I see you just posted that as a comment as I was writing this.

Comment: What do you mean by "double it?"  What result are you wanting to get?

Comment: sorry, my English is very bad but what I want to do is double the occurrence of the asterisk. So when I first get the output I get the value of hel*l*o. I want it to double the asterisk every time the letter "l" shows up. So I want it to output hel*l**o. And yes I can understand now that I do not need the double loop

Comment: So, you want `hel*l**o`?  (the markdown formatting uses `*` as bold or italic, so it got a little mangled in your comment)?

Comment: @Bhavis456 Please add your desired output to the question, not to the comments. Make sure to use code formatting, especially for text that contains asterisks (`*`). Otherwise asterisks have special meaning in the markup language on StackOveflow (*italics* or **boldface**). See also: [How to format code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/967621)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`re.sub` can accept a callable which takes the current match as an argument and returns the string with which to replace it. I'm taking advantage of a persistent default argument `it` to maintain the state of the counter.

```
import re
from itertools import count

def replace(match, it=count(1)):
    return match.group() + ("*" * next(it))

print(re.sub("l", replace, "hello world"))
```

Output:

```
hel*l**o worl***d
>>>
```

---

Or, as @tobias_k points out, if you want the asterisks to "double" each time, the definition of `replace` would be:

```
def replace(match, it=count()):
    return match.group() + ("*" * 2**next(it))
```

Output:

```
hel*l**o worl****d
>>>
```

Comment: Very nice, but OP wants to double the `*`, so `"*" * 2**(next(it)-1)`?

Comment: @tobias_k Ah - to be honest I'm still having a hard time interpreting the OP's requirements. An expected output example would have been nice :) I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.subn`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.subn), for example:

```
import re

my_str = 'hello world, hello!'
ltr = 'l'
tot_num_subs = 1
new_chars_lst = []

for old_char in my_str:
    new_chars, num_subs = re.subn(ltr, ltr + '*' * tot_num_subs, old_char)
    tot_num_subs *= 2**num_subs
    new_chars_lst += new_chars

new_str = ''.join(new_chars_lst)
print(new_str)
# hel*l**o worl****d, hel********l****************o!
```

First, the string is split into individual characters. Then, `re.subn` is applied to every character. It returns a tuple with the string after replacements (either the original character, or the original character plus an appropriate number of asterisks).

The number of asterisks starts at 1 and is either the same as before (multiplied by `2**0 = 1`), or is doubled (multiplied by `2**1 = 2`) when `ltr` is replaced.

The new strings are stored in the list `new_chars_lst`, which is finally joined together on an empty string to reconstruct the full string.